# how to mix xsd:sequence with xsd:all

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to require the first n elements to be in a sequence followed by several elements that may be in any order.

For example, lets' say I have this xml:

```
<root>
    <person>
        <fn>First name</fn>
        <ln>Last Name</ln>
        <gender>F</gender>
        <age>33</age>
        <middleName>Middle</middleName>
    </person>
</root>
```

I need to require that  has 2 first elements  and  which must be 
in that exact order,
followed by 3 elements ,  and  and these 3 can be in any order.

I tried this but it does not seem like it's a valid xml for schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="person">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="fn" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="ln" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>

            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="gender" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="age" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="middleName" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:all>

        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done directly.

You could replace the xsd:all with an xsd:choice that allows the possible 8 permutations of the three elements, which is just about manageable for three but gets unwieldy quite rapidly.

In XSD 1.1 I would suggest using an xsd:all content model and then restricting it with an assertion.

However, I would also question *why* you want to design your document this way. Where XSD doesn't allow you to do something, it's often because the designers of XSD didn't think it was a very smart thing to do.

Comment: I don't design a document. This was just a sample. The actual document is the EDI file created by the SAP software and I convert it to XML afterwards. The order of segments in EDI is not always strict but some segments are required. EDIs are complicated